# Water pump control hysteresis

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using arduino with analog pressure sensor, temperature sensor and a relay to control water pump. The simple code I wrote works, but I want better control.

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

 const int pinCidlaDS = 2;
 int pinA0 = A0;
 int teplota;
 int rele;
 float tlak = 0;  //ideal 290+-

OneWire oneWireDS(pinCidlaDS);
DallasTemperature senzoryDS(&oneWireDS);

void setup() {
 senzoryDS.begin();
 rele = 3;
 pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 tlak = analogRead(A0);
 teplota = (senzoryDS.getTempCByIndex(0));
  if ((tlak < 285) && (teplota < 30)) {
   digitalWrite(rele, LOW);
   delay(7000);
 }
   else {
   digitalWrite(rele, HIGH);
   delay(500);
 };
 Serial.print("Tlak: ");
 Serial.println(tlak);
 Serial.print("Teplota: ");
 senzoryDS.requestTemperatures();
 Serial.print(senzoryDS.getTempCByIndex(0));
 Serial.println(" stupnu Celsia");
 teplota = (senzoryDS.getTempCByIndex(0));
 delay (200);

}
```

So now I'm using delay to get away from the treshold value. And I wanted to write a code that would work like:

**Pressure is lower than 'x', relay ON.
Pressure rises to 'Y', relay OFF until Pressure is lower than 'x'.**

What should I use? Could you please give me a example, if there is? 
Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Implementing hysteresis turns out to be quite straight-forward:

```cpp
float pressure = read_pressure();
if (pressure < x)
    turn_relay_on();
else if (pressure >= y)
    turn_relay_off();
```

Comment: In addition to this answer you can also use `millis();` function instead of delay, take a look at **BlinkWithoutDelay** example in Arduino IDE.

Comment: @newbie, with appropriate hysteresis values you might not need any delay logic at all, using either `millis()` or `delay()`. The hysteresis range allows you to have a "dead zone" range where nothing changes. It takes time for the temperature to go from the temp/pressure "on value" to the "off value", so the pump turns on and off less frequently.

Comment: It looks like the OP's application makes its `pump on` /  `pump off` decisions based on both temperature **and** pressure. We need to know the values for both that should trigger the pump on, and the values that should trigger the pump to go back off again.

Comment: @DuncanC: Hysteresis on two variables is more complex. My usual approach would be to draw, in the (T, P) plane, three regions: `pump on`, `pump off`, and an hysteresis band between them. Then write a predicate on the (T, P) pair for each of `pump on` and `pump off`. Cutting out a quarter-plane (`T<T1 && P<P1` and `T>=T2 || P>=P2`) is the simplest case, but I would not trust something with such a sharp corner to be anywhere near optimal for any application.